# Local project reference is not getting resolved

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have 3 PCL projects in the same solution.

```
Robin.Models 
Robin.Services 
Robin
```

I added the reference of **Robin.Models** project in the **Robin.Services**
Both the **Robin.Models** and **Robin.Services** projects were build successfully.

Now I add the **Robin.Models** project reference to the **Robin** project.
In the **Robin** project if I am adding any one of the Projects **Models/Services** then the the corresponding objects were resolved fine.

If I add only one reference **Models** then also it is working fine.

If I add the reference of **Services** also then all the classes/objects in the **Models** project are not getting resolved.
Even the using Robin.Models statement turns red after adding the **Services** project.

Any idea what is the issue.

Comment: I don't think I understand correctly your problem. I'm getting lost of what projects have references to what projects. And where you encounter compilation errors. Maybe you can create a public repo somewhere to better illustrate this.

Comment: Please post some code/screenshots of references.